# Getting Cursor's query parameters

Tags: android, android-cursor

Is there a way of getting the parameters used to create a cursor?

```
Cursor mCursor = db.query("TABLE",
            new String[]{"_id", "NAME"}, null, null, null, null, null, "5");
```

In this cursor my parameters are the table name, the column names and the limit.

Can I get these variables later on somehow?

Comment: Not from the cursor, no. You could make some class that encapsulates the parameters and the resulting cursor and work with that instead.

Comment: You can use `cursor.getColumnNames()` which returns a string array holding the names of all of the columns in the result set in the order in which they were listed in the result. I suppose that a workaround could be to store the TableName as a field in your table. Not sure if this is the best practice for your situation though.

Comment: It seems the best way to do this would be to create a Map of parameters and then get paramater from the map when I need to query again?

Comment: If you're trying to get all the columns in the table over and over again, you should use what's called a projection. A projection is nothing more than an array that contains the names of all the columns in the table as its elements. Usually you make this projection array in your DBContract.class. Here is a [reference](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html#ContractClasses).

Comment: Actually, the columns stay the same mostly and what I really need are the limits, selection arguments (null in this case).